# ChartJS Financial candles on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, chart.js, candlestick-chart

I’m trying to make [Chartjs-chart-financial](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-chart-financial) in NodeJS. There is no NPM package for this plugin so I have to install it manually.

I do:

```
Git clone https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-chart-financial/
cd chartjs-chart-financial
npm install
gulp build
```

As result I get a file in /dist directory and copy it to my NodeJS project folder.

In my NodeJS app I do:

```
const Chart = require(‘chart.js’)
const ChartFinancial = require(‘./chartjs-chart-financial.js’)
```

When I run the app I get:

```
chartjs-chart-financial.js:227
globalOpts.elements.financial = {
TypeError: Cannot set property ‘financial’ of undefined
```

I have checked content of Chart.defaults and found that .elements is in ‘global’ so I changed

```
225 const globalOpts = Chart.defaults.global
316 const globalOpts$1 = Chart.defaults.global
401 const globalOpts$2 = Chart.defaults.global
```

And eventually Error

```
Chart.defaults.set(‘ohlc’ ... set is not a function
```

on line 446

So I changed them to:

```
446 Chart.defaults.ohlc.datasets.barPercentage = 1.0,
447 Chart.defaults.ohlc.datasets.categoryPercentage = 1.0
```

Then I got

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at CandlestickController.draw (C:\inetpub\github\telegram-stream-trades\chartjs-chart-financial.js:213:32)
```

So I chagned:

```
213 const rects = me.getMeta();
```

That handled all the errors. But still no candles drawn.

So probably the way I initially started is incorrect